# DataType Erorr : String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

---

### Asp.net cs C# Code is

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    try
    {
        //File Name
        string fn = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
        //File Save
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/PagesWith/FilesDiv/") + fn);
        //File Path
        string fPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/PagesWith/FilesDiv/") + fn;
        //File Type
        string ft = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
        // Get the length of the file.
        int fileLen = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        //File Size
        // Create a byte array to hold the contents of the file.
        byte[] input = new byte[fileLen - 1];
        input = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
        SqlParameter[] Prm = new SqlParameter[7];
        Prm[0] = new SqlParameter("@fname", txtFileNm.Text);
        Prm[1] = new SqlParameter("@fsize", input);
        Prm[2] = new SqlParameter("@ftype", ft);
        Prm[3] = new SqlParameter("@categoryID", ddlCategory.SelectedValue);
        Prm[4] = new SqlParameter("@subject", txtSubject.Text);
        Prm[5] = new SqlParameter("@comments", txtComments.Text);
        Prm[6] = new SqlParameter("@fpath", fPath);
        DB_Functions.ExcuteNonQuery("SP_A_Data", Prm);
        lblState.Text = "Your Data is Saved (: ";
        clear();
        lblState.Text = "Added";
    }
    catch( Exception ex)
    {
        lblState.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
}
else 
{
    lblState.Text="Erorr";
}
```

---

---

### Database >> Stored Procedure is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_A_Data]
(
    @fname varchar(100)=null,
    @fsize int=null,
    @ftype varchar(100)=null,
    @categoryID int=null,
    @subject varchar(50)=null,
    @comments varchar(500)=null,
    @fpath varchar(100)=null
)
AS
BEGIN
  Insert Into Data_Divs(fname,fsize,categoryID,[subject],comments,ftype,fpath)
  Values(@fname,@fsize,@categoryID,@subject,@comments,@ftype,@fpath)
End
```

---

### Erorr is

String or binary data would be truncated.
[image]

Comment: you are adding a varchar filed to you database table with a length over the maximum allowed

Comment: Could we see the structure of Data_divs table? We are entering a record in some column which the given column's data type does not like.

Comment: Generally this error occurs if the data is larger than the size of the column so you'll lose data.

Comment: did you search on google?

Comment: also instead of adding parameters like this `SqlParameter[] Prm = new SqlParameter[7];` try looking up how to use the `Command.Prameters.Add or Parameters.AddWithValue` function much cleaner in my opinion

Comment: You might also take a look this before naming your procedures sp_ http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: What is Solution please @I_am_Batman

Comment: What is Solution please @ScottMcKeand

Comment: What is Solution please @SeanLange

Comment: What is Solution please @FLICKER

Comment: Check the length of your values you are passing to "new SqlParameter(..." before your execute the query.

Comment: What is Solution please @DaniloCalzetta

Comment: give me any change good in code please mr.@FLICKER

Comment: please i need to solution of this erorr i can't continuation of my work please any help in code

Comment: You Need to check the size of the data you are passing into the SQL parameters against the size of your columns. Then you can change your column size appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to put this into comment, but it's more clear to put as answer. This may help you to find what is wrong.

```
... some code here

    Prm[5] = new SqlParameter("@comments", txtComments.Text);
    Prm[6] = new SqlParameter("@fpath", fPath);

        // add this loop into your code and trace the program. 
        foreach (var item in Prm)
        {
            var len = item.Value.ToString().Length;
            // check len to see if it is bigger than of size of the corresponding column
            // if len is bigger than your column size, that is the issue
            // and you need to alter that column to store bigger string
        }


    DB_Functions.ExcuteNonQuery("SP_A_Data", Prm);
    lblState.Text = "Your Data is Saved (: ";
    clear();
    lblState.Text = "Added";

... some code here
```

<sub>*Please "Mark as Answer" if a post has answered the question*</sub>

Comment: not big size small file sush as .txt my code trabush in Execute  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: after Execute go to Catch in class ;)